# Why are "sc.addFile" and "spark-submit --files" not distributing a local file to all workers?

Tags: file, apache-spark, cluster-computing, distribute

I have a CSV file "test.csv" that I'm trying to have copied to all nodes on the cluster.

I have a 4 node apache-spark 1.5.2 standalone cluster. There are 4 workers where one node also acts has master/driver as well as the worker.

If I run:

`$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark --files=./test.csv` OR from within the REPL interface execute `sc.addFile('file://' + '/local/path/to/test.csv')`

I see spark log the following:

```
16/05/05 15:26:08 INFO Utils: Copying /local/path/to/test.csv to /tmp/spark-5dd7fc83-a3ef-4965-95ba-1b62955fb35b/userFiles-a4cb1723-e118-4f0b-9f26-04be39e5e28d/test.csv
16/05/05 15:26:08 INFO SparkContext: Added file file:/local/path/to/test.csv at http://192.168.1.4:39578/files/test.csv with timestamp 1462461968158
```

In a separate window on the master/driver node, I can easily locate the file using ls, i.e. (`ls -al /tmp/spark-5dd7fc83-a3ef-4965-95ba-1b62955fb35b/userFiles-a4cb1723-e118-4f0b-9f26-04be39e5e28d/test.csv`).

However if I log into the the workers, there is no file at `/tmp/spark-5dd7fc83-a3ef-4965-95ba-1b62955fb35b/userFiles-a4cb1723-e118-4f0b-9f26-04be39e5e28d/test.csv` and not even a folder at `/tmp/spark-5dd7fc83-a3ef-4965-95ba-1b62955fb35b`

But the apache spark web interface shows a job running and cores allocated on all nodes, also no other warnings or errors appear in the console.

Comment: I believe that each worker manages user files independently. The log line `Copying /local/path/to/test.csv (...)` happened only in the driver. Each worker will then store the file at a different location based on its configuration, and point its name to the correct location.

Comment: Ah I thought it used a deterministic folder structure everywhere, thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Daniel commented, each worker manages files differently. If you want to access the added file, then you can use [`SparkFiles.get(file)`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkFiles$). If you want to see which directory your files are going to, then you can print the output of `SparkFiles.getDirectory` (now `SparkFiles.getRootDirectory`)